# Manhwa where the main character was reincarnated as the daughter of a noble who murdered evil people

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character was reincarnated as the daughter of a noble who murdered evil people. The sons were murderers too, but they loved her very much. All the servants loved her because she saved them from the anger of her father multiple times.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This is very 'tropey'. Can you be any more specific about the characters (ages, names, what kind of nobleman her father was, how she was reincarnated) or the manwha (where you read it, whether it was in colour, who the artist was, how long it was, how recent it was, etc)?

Comment: It was in colour, i remember that the father had dark hair .

Comment: What is a "Manwha"?

Comment: @CWallach it's Korean manga

Comment: @FrancescoGramegna How certain are you that they only murder evil people, and aren't evil themselves? If the MC protects servants from their father, they don't sound very righteous. Do you remember any specific violence against servants, e.g. a scene where a maid is decapitated on the spot for speaking out of turn? Do the family members ever try to kill each other for being too soft?